# React Native Expo set minimum iOS Deployment Target for Podfiles

Tags: ios, xcode, expo, podfile, fastlane-gym

I am trying to build my React Native app for iOS and having issues.

I build on a regular basis, but since upgrading Xcode to `15.0.1`, I have run into an issue.

I build my app for iOS as follows:

- `npx expo prebuild` -> generates my `ios` and `android` folders
- `cd ios`
- `pod install`
- Open the `ios` directory in Xcode and configure my signing and build settings
- Create a `Gymfile` in the `ios` directory with the necessary details
- `fastlane gym`
- This then gives me my `.ipa` file which I then upload to TestFlight

However, since the upgrade, when I run `fastlane gym`, it fails, with multiple logs relating to my Podfiles targeting an invalid version of iOS, these look like this:

`warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to ...`

I have tried various things to resolve this, including changes to my `Podfile`, and setting the `platform :ios,` to be `podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget']` if the value exists and is greater or equal to `12.0`, else set it to `12.0`.

I also tried manually changing the deployment target in each of the Pods in Xcode, but I have not had any success yet.

I also tried adding:

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "ios": {
        "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
      }
    }
  ]
],
```

to my `app.config.js`, but this also didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve my issue by upgrading to Expo 49, I was previously using Expo 47. My iOS builds now succeed, although my Android builds have started to fail.

Answer (score 1):

After running npx expo install --fix, I was able to build

Answer (score 0):

You can also update it on each pod using a post_install hook, something like this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end
```

After adding the above code execute the below command

```
pod install
npx expo prebuild --clean
```

Comment: Yeah I recently just saw some people with similar suggestions elsewhere. I have tried simply changing the target to ``13.0`` for all, checking the current value and setting it to ``13.0`` if it is not valid, or just deleting the value altogether. Neither actually reflected changes in Xcode.

Comment: This is the correct way to set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 13 so it will not update your Xcode IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET whenever you install pod

Comment: Is your problem solved?